# Custom permalink structure: multiple custom post types organized by language

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm trying to create custom permalink structure that will allow me to group several custom post types by language.

I've got 3 custom post types for content in English (Articles, News, Events) and 2 custom post types for content in German (Artikel, Nachrichten).

I want my permalink structure to look like this:

```
/en/articles/article-title

/en/news/news-post-title

/de/artikel/artikelüberschrift
```

or

```
/%lang%/%custom-post-type%/%post-name%/
```

It there any good solution how to include /%lang%/ argument to permalink structure?

Comment: What plugin are you using for translation?